# Where can i finde firebase authentication code?

Tags: firebase, authentication, angularfire

I have configure firebase via ng add @angular/fire.
CLI
UPDATE package.json (1096 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
? What features would you like to setup? Authentication
Using firebase-tools version 10.7.0
? Allow Firebase to collect CLI usage and error reporting information? Yes
? Enter authorization code:123

Firebase asking about authentication code but I have no any authenticaon code.
Where can i find authentication code.

Answer (score 0):

Most apps need to know the identity of a user. Knowing a user's identity allows an app to securely save user data in the cloud and provide the same personalized experience across all of the user's devices.
Firebase Authentication provides backend services, easy-to-use SDKs, and ready-made UI libraries to authenticate users to your app. It supports authentication using passwords, phone numbers, popular federated identity providers like Google, Facebook and Twitter, and more.

Firebase Authentication integrates tightly with other Firebase services, and it leverages industry standards like OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect, so it can be easily integrated with your custom backend.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to get the authorization code, but if you log through the terminal you can get around being asked to provide one.

- run `firebase login` in the terminal
- login to firebase through your browser
- then run `ng add @angular/fire`

Instead of asking you to provide an authorization code, it'll ask which firebase account you would like to use.